# Can we use energy–momentum relation with scalars to get meaningful result?

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Does energy–momentum relation (as defined in the beginning of [wiki/Energy–momentum_relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation)) meant to be used only in terms of stress-energy-momentum tensor but not with simple scalars?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you mean by using this relation for scalars. Do you mean [scalar (spin 0) particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_boson)? Or do you mean [Lorentz scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_scalar)?

Note that the relativistic energy momentum relation 'falls out of' the Lorentzian norm of the [four-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector#Four-momentum) $\mathbf{P} = m\mathbf{U}=(E/c,\mathbf{p})$:

$$||\mathbf{P}||^2 = \frac{E^2}{c^2}-p^2 = m^2||\mathbf{U}||^2 = m^2c^2$$

Solving for $E^2$ yields

$$E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$$